# Can't add item to Observable Collection (or UI is not being refreshed)

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a noob problem. As the title says, I'm having a problem with an observable collection. 
I'm trying to fill a collection passing a value trough a TextBox, and then adding it to an observable collection. When I press the button "*Add Ciudad*", a TextBox to insert the new value and a button to save it is displayed.
The value gets successfully to the method in charge of doing that ("*Add Input City*"), but the UI never shows the new item.
By the way, the first value added manually in "*Load Ciudades*" shows properly.

I saw some related questions, but still I'm not able to solve the problem.

I suspect I'm not properly adding the items. For more trouble, I'm a completely noob with C# :D.
Here's the code so you can judge:

**Cities model:**

```
public class Ciudad : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string nombre;

    public String Nombre
    {
        get { return nombre; }

        set {
                nombre = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Nombre");
                RaisePropertyChanged("Ciudades"); //Dunno if this one is necesary.
            }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

**Cities view model:**

```
public ObservableCollection<Ciudad> Ciudades { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Ciudad>();

    public void LoadCiudades()
    {
        Ciudades.Add(new Ciudad { Nombre = "Random city" });
    }

    public void AddInputCity(string new_city)
    {
        Ciudades.Add(new Ciudad { Nombre = new_city });
    }
```

**Cities view:**

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource = "{ Binding Path = Ciudades, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }" Name="DGrid">

    </DataGrid>
    <Button Click="Button_Click" Height="30" Width="150" Margin="0,250,0,0">Add Ciudad</Button></Grid>
```

**Cities view cs**

```
TextBox iTextBox;

    public CiudadesView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Add_Input_Text()
    {
        TextBox iText = new TextBox
        {
            Name = "iText",
            Width = 250,
            Margin = new Thickness(100)
        };

        Button saveBtn = new Button()
        {
            Content = "Save"
        };
        saveBtn.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(Button_Save_Click);

        sPanel.Children.Add(iText);
        sPanel.Children.Add(saveBtn);
        iTextBox = iText;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Add_Input_Text();
    }

    private void Button_Save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string ciudadNuevoNombre = iTextBox.Text;
        CiudadesViewModel viewModel = new CiudadesViewModel();
        viewModel.AddInputCity(ciudadNuevoNombre);
    }
```

Any ideas or suggestions?
Thank you all! : )

Comment: You probably create two Cities view model instances by accident (this is usually the case for problems like that). One of those instances is bound to your UI, whereas your code then later changes the collection of the accidentally created and unbound second view model instance. Check and review your code to see whether this is the case, and make sure your UI and your code-behind use the same single Cities view model instance.

Comment: Please post the code for your Button_Click event handler.

Comment: As a note, `RaisePropertyChanged("Ciudades")` is of course not necessary. Also, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the ItemsSource Binding is pointless. It has no effect there.

Comment: Button code added.

Thanks for the suggestions! The "instances thing" was the problem. I was creating two instances by accident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you call the `AddInputCity` method of the *existing* view model instance in your `Button_Click` event handler, e.g.:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var viewModel = DataContext as YourViewModelClass;
    if (viewModel != null)
        viewModel.AddInputCity("new...");
}
```

Comment: Awesome! As you people said, I was creating another instance by mistake. This code fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You've not shown us your click code and several other things like the relationship between view and viewmodel.
I suggest you also take a look at binding commands rather than click handlers.
This is an article intended to introduce the reader to MVVM which adds an item to a bound observablecollection using a command:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32164.wpf-mvvm-step-by-step-2.aspx